# text field value not becoming empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where the input fields need to become empty when they have focus. Its working well on all pages except for page of certain type where there is another js running.

http://www.iamvishal.com/residen/?q=node/70 - not working

// here I have another js running at the below as a before and after slider.
// I am not getting any errors here but I don't know what might be causing it.
// I suspect something is wrong between these two.

http://www.iamvishal.com/residen/?q=node/54 - working example here

below is my code

```
$('input[type=text]').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val("");

    }); // end of focus function


$('input[type=email]').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val("");

    }); // end of focus function


$('#edit-submitted-messaggio').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val("");

    }); // end of focus function
```

Comment: The `.value` of an input can never be `null`. I can be `""` at best.

Comment: I  meant "" it should look empty to the user

Comment: Maybe there is **Conflict** between jquery and other framework ,change $ to jQuery in all your code and test http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ ,look also also see console , it shows errors

Comment: try using $(this).attr('value',''); 
Maybe val() is only for getting.

Comment: If the difference between the pages is the "other js" running, chances are that's very relevant. If you can't post the full thing, could you at least look it over and give a general idea of what it does? I think a lot of this debugging may have to be on your end, as SO tends to be for issues specific to a small, reproducible piece of code.

Comment: Firebug is displaying a JS error on the page that doesn't work. If you fix this all should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple, nested "onready" calls (`$(function(){ ... });`)

The `.focus(function(){ .. });` code is wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });` which is also wrapped in an `$(function(){ ... });`. Make sure you have only one `$(function(){ ... });`!

```
$(function() {
    // EVERY jQuery code goes here
});
```

Comment: I was able to correct it on my dev machine based on your suggestion. May I know how u found this out ? I don't see any errors its a real pain

Comment: I think initialization logic is one of the easier things for code-reviewers to look at; . The nesting is like this: Racing light turns green. The racing coach was waiting for this, reacts immediately, tells the driver: "When that light turns green, GO!" Racing driver grips the wheel and waits for the light to 'turn' green. (again). He'll be waiting a long time.

Comment: I found out by looking at your code. (after 'prettifying' it). Nice explanation @Katana314

Answer (score 0):

On your first page, there's a conflict between `jQuery` and some other script using the `$` symbol. This should work for you:

```
jQuery('input[type=text]').focus(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).val("");

    }); // end of focus function


jQuery('input[type=email]').focus(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).val("");

    }); // end of focus function


jQuery('#edit-submitted-messaggio').focus(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).val("");

    }); // end of focus function
```